# Prevent direct access to an action controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working with zend framework. In a view i use an action helper.

`echo $this->action('info', 'comment', null, array('articleID' => $article->arti_id));`

So, the helper call 'CommentController' class and method 'infoAction'. Inside my method i get the 'articleID' param and i begin process with model. Finally i render a shared view.

```
public function infoAction() {
    $articleID = $this->getRequest()->getParam('articleID');
    // Working with model
            // .....
    $this->renderScript('/View/Script/DefaultComment.phtml');
}
```

It's work well but i don't want that this controller/action be directly accessible by the url `domain.com/comment/info`.

How can i avoid this ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your action method is always called with an article id parameter, then you could redirect the request in case there is no id:

```
public function infoAction() {
    if ($this->_hasParam('articleID')) {
        $articleID = $this->getRequest()->getParam('articleID');
        // Working with model
            // .....
    $this->renderScript('/View/Script/DefaultComment.phtml');
    } else {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index', 'default');
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but since your URL is visible in your code source, it shouldn't be a security exploit to access this page directly. But a broker page could occurred... you have to know that action() is very expensive and a View Helper would be more appropriate in order to realize this kind of action.

Comment: Finally, i create a view Helper and i render my view. As you say, Controllers must stay public/accessible. My helper is more protected. Thanks